# Imported repo does not import the projects within

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, github, repository

the title says most of it. I also checked the "Import all existing Eclipse projects after clone finishes". I am starting to learn github. Please help me and make this a pleasent start so I actually keep using it. The repo folder that I had to choose for the repo is not in my eclipse workspace. I thought I don't need to manually import the projects in the repo if I check that checkbox. I use eclipse Mars and EGit.

Edit: I created a new repository before on GitHub. I imported a test project into my repository to play around with it and test stuff. Thats all whats in the repository.

Thats what my GitHub repo looks like on the website:
[image]

Apprecciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse will only import *Eclipse projects*. So if you have some plain Java projects (without Eclipse specific meta data) or even just plain folders in your repository, those will not be imported. However, you can import all such non Eclipse artifacts into Eclipse projects by using the "Import -> General" wizard category.

And in case your projects *are* Eclipse projects, you can re-try the import from the locally cloned repository into your workspace by using the "Import projects" menu on the repository in the repository view of Eclipse.